# Validation Throwing hard errors instead of validation rule errors

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5

I have a view with a field like this

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => 'manufacturers/'.$manufacturer->id , 'method' => 'put')) !!}

<div class="col-lg-6">
   {!! Form::text('manufacturer_name', $vehicle->manufacturer_name, array('placeholder' => 'Manufacturer Name', 'class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '')) !!}
</div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

And in my Validation Rules i have

```
return [
'manufacturer_name' => 'required|max:20'
];
```

If i a add more than 20 characters in the manufacturer_name, i recieve the below error.

**htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**

Now if i increase the max value to 30 the data is added to the db just fine. But Laravel should send back nice validation errors not the hard php errors.

As always any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a separate request for that or just using the plain `validate` function in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue, In my case i was dynamically adding some fields so i migrated some code from the create view. **I forgot to remove/replace the Old input value with the new data from database**. It has been giving me headaches for an hour now.

```
 <input type="text" name="link_url" value="{{ Input::old('link_url') }}" />
```